# Is there any problem with wearing Techeles if it is not the real one?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, techeles, contemporary-halacha

Many people hold the murex trunculus is the real techeles, and many others hold it is not.

Would there be any Halachic problem of wearing it if it is not real?